# Overriding a Puppet Class when using Inheritance

Tags: linux, inheritance, puppet, sudo

I'm trying to use class inheritance for puppet. There is a base class named **foo** and an inherited class named **bar**. Overriding `file` or `package` resources are quite fine and works properly. But at the same time i'm using a custom module for configuring `sudo`.

The problem arises when i try to override `sudo` class from inside class **bar**. Puppet classes are as follows:

```
 class foo {
  $nrpe_plugin_pkgs = [ .... ]

  service { 'nrpe service':
    ..
  }

  package { $nrpe_plugin_pkgs:
    ..
  }

  file { '/etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg':
    ..
  }

  file { '/etc/resolv.conf':
    ..
  }

  class { 'sudo':
    purge               => true,
    config_file_replace => true,
  }

  sudo::conf { 'sudo_conf':
    priority => 10,
    content  => [
      '%gr1 ALL=(userfoo) NOPASSWD: ALL',
      '%gr1 ALL=(root)  NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/wbinfo *',
    ]
  }
}


class bar inherits foo {
  File['/etc/resolv.conf'] {
    ..
  }

  sudo::conf { 'sudo_conf':
    priority => 10,
    content  => [
      '%gr2     ALL=NOPASSWD:/bin/chown userbar\:gr2 /dirbar/*',
      '%gr2     ALL=NOPASSWD:/bin/chown -R userbar\:gr2 /dirbar/*',
      '%gr2     ALL=NOPASSWD:/bin/chmod * /dirbar/*',
    ]
  }
}
```

I just want to customize only **resolv.conf** and **sudo** config, but i'm getting error as follows:

> Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Evaluation Error: Error
>   while evaluating a Resource Statement, Duplicate declaration:
>   Sudo::Conf[sudo_conf] is already declared in file
>   /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/foobar_servers/manifests/foobar.pp:80;
>   cannot redeclare at
>   /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/foobar_servers/manifests/foobar.pp:335
>   at
>   /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/foobar_servers/manifests/foobar.pp:335:3
>   on node foobartest01

**/etc/sudoers.d/10_sudo_conf** file expected to be created. How can i achieve that?

Using: Puppet 4.9 Community version.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resolv.conf override works here, because you're using [the correct syntax](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/lang_classes.html#overriding-resource-attributes):

```
class bar inherits foo {
  File['/etc/resolv.conf'] {
    ..
  }
```

But the syntax for the next line where you try to override is different, so it fails:

```
sudo::conf { 'sudo_conf':
```

This is the syntax to [*declare* a new resource](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/lang_resources.html#simplified-syntax) (hence why you get a duplicate error) rather than [to override an existing resource](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/lang_classes.html#overriding-resource-attributes). It should be:

```
Sudo::Conf['sudo_conf'] {
  priority => 10,
  content  => [
    '%gr2     ALL=NOPASSWD:/bin/chown userbar\:gr2 /dirbar/*',
    '%gr2     ALL=NOPASSWD:/bin/chown -R userbar\:gr2 /dirbar/*',
    '%gr2     ALL=NOPASSWD:/bin/chmod * /dirbar/*',
  ]
}
```